# How to create table migration in Laravel 5

Tags: php, model, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I am working on a project where, I have been assigned a task to create user management for the application. But I have stuck on the table relationship and their migration.

**Effort**

I have these tables:

1. Users

   - user_id
   - username
   - password
2. Profiles

   - profile_id
   - user_id
   - firstname
   - lastname
   - email
3. Address

   - address_id
   - profile_id
   - address
   - city
   - state
   - country
   - pincode
4. Configurations

   - config_id
   - configuration_name
   - configuration_type
   - parent_id

Now I have to create model and migration for the same above structure. For this i have create/modify below model and migration class.

**Model: User**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile','user_id');
    }
}
```

**Migration: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('user_id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

**Model: Profile**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Address','address_id');
    }
}
```

**Migration: 2016_02_26_101749_create_profiles_table.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('profile_id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('lastname')->nullable();
            $table->string('firstname')->nullable();
            $table->string('gender')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('phonenumber', 20)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('profiles');
    }
}
```

**Model: Addess**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    public function profile(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Profile');
    }

    public function city() {
        return $this->hasOne('Configuration', 'config_id');
    }

    public function state() {
      return $this->hasOne('Configuration', 'config_id');
    }

    public function country() {
        return $this->hasOne('Configuration', 'config_id');
    }
}
```

**Migration: 2016_02_26_102805_create_addresses_table.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAddressesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('address_id');
            $table->integer('profile_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('profile_id')->references('profile_id')->on('profiles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->integer('city')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('city')->references('config_id')->on('configurations')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('pincode')->nullable();
            $table->integer('state')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('state')->references('config_id')->on('configurations')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('country')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('country')->references('config_id')->on('configurations')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('addresses');
    }
}
```

**Model: Configuration**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Configuration extends Model
{
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('Configuration','parent_id');
    }
    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Configuration','parent_id');
    }
   public function address(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Address');
    }
}
```

**Migration: 2016_02_26_104519_create_configurations_table.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateConfigurationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('configurations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('config_id');
            $table->string('configuration_name');
            $table->string('configuration_type');
            $table->string('parent_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('configurations');
    }
}
```

Now, when I run `php artisan migrate` I am getting error that :

[image: migration error] .

Please suggest me how to do that. I have to use same table structure and cannot modify it. If any further update require or I forgot something please let me know.

Comment: i have created user_id not id in migration table. So, i think that is not the issue. I think issue is with the address and configuration as, address contain city, state,country columns and these columns will be the foreign key from configurations table.

Comment: Yeah sorry i realised after i posted the comment that your column name is `user_id` in `user` table - confused me for a moment. I deleted the comment.

Comment: Run migrations separetely to see which one is giving you the error.

Comment: Ok, I will try. I have tried, but i did not find anything to run seprate migration for each table. Please suggest me how to run migration sepratly for each model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happen because migration will try to migrate address table before configuration so it will not found the foreign key `config_id` you're referenced, so you could change the name of migrations files then the `migration` commad could pass the `configurations_table` migrate file first then the `addresses_table` migrate file, so just change :

```
2016_02_26_104519_create_configurations_table.php
```

To :

```
2016_02_26_102005_create_configurations_table.php
_____________^
```

After that you should run optimize command to regenerating optimized class loader :

```
php artisan o
```

And rerun `php artisan migrate` command now the problem should be solved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, It solved my issue. Could you please tell me is my model and their relationship is ok.

Comment: Not sure, first time i see same column (`config_id`) represent different informations (city, state, country) not sure if it will works.